# Why I am not able to update the imageurl using these functions in firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have initialized url to null at first then i am adding data in my firestore first document and then image

```
  String url='';
  StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot;

  Future<Project> updateUserData(Project project) async {
   docref=await  firestoreInstance.collection('projects').add(
      {
        'id': project.id,
        'title': project.title,
        'description': project.description,
        'duration': project.duration,
        'members': project.members,
        'complexity': project.complexity,
        'affordability': project.affordability,
        'prequisites': project.prequisites,
        'contact': project.contact,
        'imageurl': 'https://bitsofco.de/content/images/2018/12/broken-1.png',
      },
    );

    
    
    fileName = basename(project.image.path);
     firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
     uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(project.image);
     

    String photourl =  await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    url= photourl.toString();  //updating the null initialized url here
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Then i am using this function to update the imageurl in the previously saved doc.

```
  Future<Void> updatedata() async{

  await  Firestore.instance
  .collection('projects')
    .document(docref.documentID)
      .updateData({
        'imageurl': url, 
        
      });
      notifyListeners();
  }
```

Everytime im calling these two functions in another widget using provide,r doc and image are getting uploaded but url is returning null and im not able to fetch the image.

```
Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context,listen: false).updateUserData(finalproj);
Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context,listen: false).updatedata();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to wait for `updateUserData` to be finished before calling `updatedata`, otherwise you can't be certain that `docref`  is set correctly.

```
await Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context,listen: false).updateUserData(finalproj);
Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context,listen: false).updatedata();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked and i am so close to complete my project now.